# ASP.NET C# GridView - Focus on RowEditing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a large dataset binding to a gridview that is inside of a 300px height restricted DIV tag. When I select a row and trigger the edit function the page reloads the data (as desired) into the gridview and takes me back to the top regardless of how far I may have scrolled down.

Is there a way ideally only using asp.net c# to focus on the row that is being edited. I don't mind if this involves the row being placed at the top of the grid while in edit mode if that is required.

Below is CountryGrid.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageSimple.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="CountryGrid.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="CountryGrid"
    Title="JFA Admin Portal - OP49 Country Update" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

            <ContentTemplate>
            <center>
            <div class="headlanding">
                           <asp:Label ID="lb_Welcome" runat="server" CssClass="labelLargeFont" Text="Label">OP49 - Country Update</asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="labelLargeFont" >You are currently modifying: </asp:Label> 
                            <asp:Label ID="Country" runat="server" CssClass="labelLargeFont" />
                        <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="labelLargeFont" >For </asp:Label> 
                            <asp:Label ID="Season" runat="server" CssClass="labelLargeFont" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </div>                                 
                    <br />
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Error_Dashboard" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="ErrorAccess" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>

                </center>
                </div>    

                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" CssClass="Grid_Panel" GroupingText="OP49 - Update Grid" Font-Bold="true">
                    <center>
                        <div style="max-height: 550px; overflow: auto;">
                        <asp:GridView ID="CountryGridView" DataKeyNames="i_SK_Accom" runat="server" Postback="False"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" RowStyle-CssClass="normal" Width="95%" 
                            OnRowEditing="CountryGridView_RowEditing" 
                            OnRowCancelingEdit="CountryGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
                            OnRowUpdating="CountryGridView_RowUpdating" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Accom Code">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lb_Accom_Code" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Accom_Code") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Accom_Code" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Accom_Code") %>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
                                    <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Accom Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lb_Accom_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Accom_Name") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Accom_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Accom_Name") %>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
                                    <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OP49 Required?">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txt_OP49" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("OP49_Required") %>' CssClass="DropBoxYN">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lb_OP49" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OP49_Required") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weekly">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txt_Weekly" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Weekly") %>'  CssClass="DropBoxYN">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lb_Weekly" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Weekly") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Daily">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txt_Daily" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Daily") %>' CssClass="DropBoxYN">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lb_Daily" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Daily") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="bt_Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" AlternateText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif" CssClass="ImageButton" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="bt_Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" AlternateText="Update" ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" CssClass="ImageButton" />
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="bt_Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" AlternateText="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" CssClass="ImageButton" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="60px" Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="Home" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/home.png" CssClass="ImageButtonLarge" AlternateText="Home" ToolTip="Home" OnClick="Click_Home" />
                    </center>
                </asp:Panel>        
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And the code behind page:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

public partial class CountryGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SnowballInterface conn = new SnowballInterface();
    SnowballInterface CurSeason = new SnowballInterface();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["i_FK_CountryID"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }

        #region Get Accom Data
        SqlCommand EditCOComm = new SqlCommand("IFACE_JFA_COUNTRY", conn.sbConn);
        EditCOComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        EditCOComm.Parameters.Add("@Statement", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "CountryDetails";
        EditCOComm.Parameters.Add("@i_FK_CountryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request["i_FK_CountryID"].Trim().ToString();

        try
        {
            conn.sbConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader EditCOReader;
            EditCOReader = EditCOComm.ExecuteReader();
            // Download default values
            while (EditCOReader.Read())
            {
                Country.Text = Convert.ToString(EditCOReader["Country_Name"]).Trim();
                Season.Text = Convert.ToString(EditCOReader["Season_Name"]).Trim();
            }

            EditCOReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.sbConn.Close();
        }
        #endregion

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindCountryGrid();
        }
    }

    protected void CountryGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the edit index.
        CountryGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindCountryGrid();            
    }

    protected void CountryGridView_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //Reset the edit index.
        CountryGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindCountryGrid();
    }

    protected void CountryGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Label Textbox_Accom = (Label)CountryGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_Accom_Code");
        Label Textbox_Accom_Name = (Label)CountryGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_Accom_Name");
        DropDownList Textbox_OP49 = (DropDownList)CountryGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_OP49");
        DropDownList Textbox_Weekly = (DropDownList)CountryGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Weekly");
        DropDownList Textbox_Daily = (DropDownList)CountryGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Daily");

        SqlCommand commEditConsultant = new SqlCommand("IFACE_JFA_ACCOM", conn.sbConn);
        commEditConsultant.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@Statement", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "AccomGridUpdate";
            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@Page", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "OP49";
            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@PC_Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper().ToString();
            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@Season_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Season.Text;
            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@Accom_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Textbox_Accom.Text;
            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@i_FK_SeasonID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Request["i_FK_SeasonID"].Trim().ToString();
            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@OP49_Required", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Textbox_OP49.Text;
            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@Weekly", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Textbox_Weekly.Text;
            commEditConsultant.Parameters.Add("@Daily", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Textbox_Daily.Text;

            conn.sbConn.Open();
                commEditConsultant.ExecuteNonQuery();
                CountryGridView.EditIndex = -1;
                Error_Dashboard.Text = Textbox_Accom.Text + " - " + Textbox_Accom_Name.Text + " Updated Successfully!";
            conn.sbConn.Close();    
                BindCountryGrid();


    }

    private void BindCountryGrid()
    {
        SqlCommand CountryGridSelect = new SqlCommand("IFACE_JFA_ACCOM", conn.sbConn);
        CountryGridSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        CountryGridSelect.Parameters.Add("@Statement", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "CountryGridSelect";
        CountryGridSelect.Parameters.Add("@i_FK_CountryID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Request["i_FK_CountryID"].Trim().ToString();

        try
        {
            conn.sbConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader CountryGridSelectReader;
            CountryGridSelectReader = CountryGridSelect.ExecuteReader();
            CountryGridView.DataSource = CountryGridSelectReader;
            CountryGridView.DataBind();
            CountryGridSelectReader.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.sbConn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void Click_Home(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?i_FK_SeasonID=" + Request["i_FK_SeasonID"].Trim().ToString());
    }    

}
```

Comment: Sorry had to remove some test code i had in place that wasn't required nor working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set  **MaintanScrollPositionOnPostback** to true in page directives on your aspx page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" CodeBehind="Gridview.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWebsite.Gridview" %>
```

Comment: Thanks Damien. This works on the main pages scroll but not on the DIV scroll region. With that said there is no reason other than display purposes to keep the DIV region but would be interesting to know how to get the DIV to do the same function.